# How can we add auto incremented column in gridpanel ext js 4.2

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

In grid Panel i want to show auto incremented row with column Id how can i achieve this?
e.g:

```
    ID     Name    Age
    1       A      52 
    2       B      25  
    3       C      20 
    4       D      20
    5       E      30
```

and if we delete record ID no. 3 then increment value will be changed too.

```
    ID     Name    Age
    1       A      52 
    2       B      25  
    3       D      20
    4       E      30
```

with regards 
vik

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for display purposes only then [`Ext.grid.column.RowNumberer`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.RowNumberer).

If you really need the numbering data store in the record then you need to listen to store data manipulation events and update the order field (ID) from the listeners.

Comment: Thanks for reply, on more thing i m able to hide the rows using below code:
**page.gridPanel.getView().getRow(rowIndex).style.display = 'none';**. but how can i unhide them ??? i tried with  'block' but its throwing error: type error undefined.. ?? could you help me on this.. ?